# 2captcha flags ERROR_WRONG_GOOGLEKEY but I have supplied one. Is this actually an ERROR_GOOGLEKEY?

Tags: rest, recaptcha, 2captcha

This is the output from having put `debug_dump` on the request. I've anonymized it slightly. Notice that there *is* a `googlekey`. The value may be wrong. I'm okay with that. What's bothering me is that `ERROR_WRONG_GOOGLEKEY` is the wrong error. I should be getting `ERROR_GOOGLEKEY` according to the [documentation](https://2captcha.com/2captcha-api#error_handling). Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be a way of telling the manufacturer.

```json
array(5) {
    ["key"] => string(32)"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz123456"["method"] => string(13)"userrecaptcha"["googlekey"] => string(32)"AHrlqAAAAAMA1lbzEUS-vFQADUZYaQ=="["pageurl"] => string(305)"https://geo.captcha-delivery.com/captcha/?initialCid=AHrlqAAAAAMA1lbzEUS-vFQADUZYaQ%3D%3D&hash=C0705ACD75EBF650A07FF8291D3528&cid=6Qx6Bz.9PraEeBk2OzH7l0MvnL7u3mRuLT47Kl3GY_Xrjo_xmXtrPY0KHZZqOC1Gokiep~w7s9mY1g_DE~xZ_aKzE2sw-KN2O-6_D0Q~7E&t=fe&referer=https%3A%2F%2Fasomeone.co%2F&s=6522"["debug_dump"] => string(1)"1"
}
array(0) {}
array(0) {}
```

Comment: You're ok with the googlekey being wrong? Why not put the right one there? It's the one that says "sitekey".

Comment: Yes, it's the one found in the IFRAME. And I did finally work out how to get that by capturing all the local cookies and transmitting them with the HTTP request for the  IFRAME src. In any case, I was grumbling about documentation and didn't know (until pointed out by my boss) that support tickets can be raised with the manufacturer.